# Workaround for doctrine generator in PSR-4 codebase

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, psr-0, symfony-console

With Symfony 2 & Doctrine on a Windows machine I'm trying to

1. generate entities from an existing schema:

   `php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force CoreBundle annotation`
2. generate getters/setters on them:

   `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities --path=/path/to/codebase/src/MyProject/CoreBundle/Entities CoreBundle`
3. generate REST CRUD controllers on them using [Voryx](https://github.com/voryx/restgeneratorbundle):

   `php app/console voryx:generate:rest --entity="CoreBundle:User"`

The first steps works fine and I can find the entities in my CoreBundle/Entity folder with the correct namespace:

```
MyVendor\MyProject\CoreBundle\Entity
```

Good so far.
However, running the other 2 commands will fail:

```
[RuntimeException]
Can't find base path for "CoreBundle" (path: 
"\path\to\codebase\src\MyProject\CoreBundle", destination: 
"/path/to/codebase/src/MyProject/CoreBundle").
```

The autoload in my composer.json looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyVendor\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

I found out that [Doctrine can't deal with PSR-4 namespaces](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/282), that's probably what makes it fail.

I would really like the entities to live in the PSR-4 CoreBundle though - is there a workaround for it?

I tried this, but it doesn't work, either:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "MyVendor\\MyProject\\CoreBundle\\Entity": "src/MyProject/CoreBundle/Entity/"
    },
    "psr-4": {
        "MyVendor\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User janvennemann on GitHub fixed Doctrine for PSR-4. You can find the [patch on Gist](https://gist.github.com/janvennemann/46b2626eee2a4808ed75), or linked here below

### Step to fix it

1. `mkdir -p app/VendorOverride`;
2. `cp vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Mapping/DisconnectedMetadataFactory.php app/VendorOverride/DisconnectedMetadataFactory.php`;
3. apply the DisconnectedMetadataFactory patch;
4. add `app/VendorOverride` to the `classmap` section in `composer.json`;
5. run `composer dump-autoload`.

Then almost all scaffolding command works.

### DisconnectedMetadataFactory PSR-4 patch

```
/**
 * Get a base path for a class
 *
 * @param string $name      class name
 * @param string $namespace class namespace
 * @param string $path      class path
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws \RuntimeException When base path not found
 */
private function getBasePathForClass($name, $namespace, $path)
{
    $composerClassLoader = $this->getComposerClassLoader();
    if ($composerClassLoader !== NULL) {
        $psr4Paths = $this->findPathsByPsr4Prefix($namespace, $composerClassLoader);
        if ($psr4Paths !== array()) {
            // We just use the first path for now
            return $psr4Paths[0];
        }
    }

    $namespace = str_replace('\\', '/', $namespace);
    $search = str_replace('\\', '/', $path);
    $destination = str_replace('/'.$namespace, '', $search, $c);

    if ($c != 1) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Can\'t find base path for "%s" (path: "%s", destination: "%s").', $name, $path, $destination));
    }

    return $destination;
}

/**
 * Gets the composer class loader from the list of registered autoloaders
 *
 * @return \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
 */
private function getComposerClassLoader() {
    $activeAutloaders = spl_autoload_functions();
    foreach($activeAutloaders as $autoloaderFunction) {
        if (!is_array($autoloaderFunction)) {
            continue;
        }

        $classLoader = $autoloaderFunction[0];
        if ($classLoader instanceof \Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader) {
            $classLoader = $classLoader->getClassLoader()[0];
        }

        if (!is_object($classLoader)) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($classLoader instanceof \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader) {
            return $classLoader;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

/**
 * Matches the namespace against all registered psr4 prefixes and
 * returns their mapped paths if found
 *
 * @param string $namespace The full namespace to search for
 * @param \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $composerClassLoader A composer class loader instance to get the list of psr4 preixes from
 * @return array The found paths for the namespace or an empty array if none matched
 */
private function findPathsByPsr4Prefix($namespace, $composerClassLoader) {
    foreach ($composerClassLoader->getPrefixesPsr4() as $prefix => $paths) {
        if (strpos($namespace, $prefix) === 0) {
            return $paths;
        }
    }

    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If somebody comes across this issue.. I got it finally working. I'm not quite sure what exactly fixed it, so here are all the steps I did:

1. As I was running Symfony 2.3, first [I upgraded to 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570276/symfony2-lts-how-to-upgrade-from-2-3-to-2-7)
2. I re-generated the bundle from scratch... I changed the location of the bundle to `MyProject\CoreBundle` and renamed the bundle class to MyProjectCoreBundle.

I can now run all of these commands successfully:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force MyProjectCoreBundle annotation
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyProjectCoreBundle
php app/console doctrine:generate:form MyProjectCoreBundle:User
php app/console voryx:generate:rest --entity=MyProjectCoreBundle:User
```

(Note that the call of `doctrine:generate:form` was not in the OP.)

My best guess is that one step of the upgrade was to change the composer autoload - this, or the 2.7 autoloader, seems to have fixed it:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/" }
},
```