# Composer error while updating symfony 2.8 to 3.0

Tags: symfony

I have successfully updated my Symfony version from 2.5 to 2.8 and deleted all my calls to deprecated methos. So now, I want to update to 3.0.*. So I updated my composer.json with `"symfony/symfony": "3.0.*"` and runned `composer update symfony/symfony`, but I get the following error in the console :

```
λ composer update symfony/symfony
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.1
    - sensio/generator-bundle v2.5.3 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.8], symfony/framework-bundle[v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - sensio/generator-bundle v2.5.3 requires symfony/console ~2.5 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.8], symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - sensio/generator-bundle v2.5.3 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.8], symfony/framework-bundle[v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.13
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.14
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.15
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.16
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.17
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.18
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.19
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.20
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.21
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.22
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.23
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.24
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.25
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.26
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.27
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.28
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.29
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.30
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.31
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.32
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.33
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.34
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.35
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.36
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.37
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.38
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.39
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.40
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.41
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.42
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.13
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.13
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.14
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.15
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.16
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.9
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v2.8.8].
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.7.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/console v2.8.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9].
    - Installation request for sensio/generator-bundle (locked at v2.5.3, required as ~2.3) -> satisfiable by sensio/generator-bundle[v2.5.3].
```

Here is my `composer.json` :

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
        "oh/instagram-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4",
        "imagine/imagine": "0.6.*",
        "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "2.6.*@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
            "keep-outdated": true
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody find what's wrong with my setup ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: It looks like you have some bundles that have conflicting requirements. `sensio/generator-bundle` is an example of this. I would follow the advice at https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/bundles.html to make sure all your project dependencies are up-to-date and compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in the [upgrade from Symfony 2.3 to 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570276/symfony2-lts-how-to-upgrade-from-2-3-to-2-7/30572402#30572402), you have to update all the dependencies, not the `symfony/symfony` package only.

We can use GitHub in order to generate the [diff between Symfony 2.8 and 3.0](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/compare/2.8...3.0#diff-b5d0ee8c97c7abd7e3fa29b9a27d1780) (if the diff for the `composer.json` file is not displayed, click on *Files changed* tab, then *26 changed files* and finally *composer.json*):

```
         "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
         "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
     },
+    "autoload-dev": {
+        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
+    },
     "require": {
-        "php": ">=5.3.9",
-        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
-        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
-        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
-        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
-        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
-        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
+        "php": ">=5.5.9",
+        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
+        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
+        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
+        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
+        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
+        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
+        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
         "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
-        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
+        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0"
     },
     "require-dev": {
-        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
-        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
+        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
+        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
     },
     "scripts": {
         "post-install-cmd": [
```

So you should use a `composer.json` like this:

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        …
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0"
    },
```

And conflicts between packages should not appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line:

```
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
},
```

to

```
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0"
},
```

Generator bundle version 2.3 is incompatible with Symfony 3.0